# EGit keeps showing outgoing on feature branch

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using EGit 2.1.0 in eclipse juno.

I have created a feature branch from my master branch. I have made some commits on the feature which I have pushed. But EGit keeps showing that my branch has outgoing. If switch to the master and merge the changes from the branch into the master and switch back to the branch the outgoing are gone on the branch. Is this a bug in EGit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have configured your feature branch to track the master branch. Usually, a local branch tracks a remote branch, but it's also possible to track another local branch.

To check that, go to the *Git Repositories* view, open the context menu of the feature branch and select *Configure Branch...*. If the origin there is ".", the specified local branch is tracked.

In that case, EGit's behavior here is correct as the feature branch is "ahead" of master until you merge those changes into master.

Comment: Your are absolutely right :-) The "Upstream Branch" says: "refs/heads/master" so I am pulling from the local master branch. The "Remote" says "." which if I understand you correct is synonymous for "local".